# Special Relativity question spaceship shooting shuttle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

This problem is eating me out from the inside. What am I doing wrong on the last part of 7b??? I even tried doing the problem from different frames.
Someone on reddit explained me this, but I still feel uncomfortable around it.
[Click here for explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/l9hgtj/special_relativity_question/)
What do you think?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty with special relativity, for many, is that not just time durations and lengths/distances are relative (in the sense that they depend on the observer); the same is true of *simultaneity*: which events happen at the same time? Two events that X thinks happen simultaneously, happen at different times according to B.

Let's distinguish a few events in your scenario:

- **event 1**: X's clock is at $t' = 9.2$ yr
- **event 2**: Y arrives at B
- **event 3**: X's clock is at $t' = 10.7$ yr

As the correct answer notes, *according to X* event 1 is simultaneous with event 2. But what your handwritten answer is calculating is the simultaneity *according to B*. For B, event 2 is simultaneous with event 3: B will argue, after doing some observations, that X's clock was at 10.7 at the moment when Y arrived at B.

Since question 7b is asking for the result according to X, 9.2 yr is the right answer.

A basic example that shows the relativity of simultaneity is synchronizing two clocks. A guy in the middle of a speeding train flashes a light bulb, and at each end of the train is a clock with a light receptor. When a clock receives the light flash it sets itself to 12.00. So after this procedure, the clocks are synchronized - according to the guy in the train. But if you were observing from outside, you have concluded that the clock in the back of the train received the signal before the other one (because the speed of the light signals is constant relative to *you*, and one clock was speeding toward it). So that clock must be running ahead of the other one. A little later, the two events of the clocks indicating 12.30 are simultaneous according to the train's movement system, but not according to your movement system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your work is rather reader unfriendly. It's hand-written rather than using MathJax (SE policy is to prefer MathJax rendered work rather than screenshots), and there isn't much explanation for what you're doing. However, I think that the central error is in using $t'=\gamma t$. You seem to have forgotten that the conversion formula for Lorentz transformations is $t'=\gamma t - \frac{\gamma vx}{c^2}$. As memorization often reflects understanding, this suggests that you have failed to internalize a central principle of relativity; you think of conversion from one frame to another as a *scaling* rather than a *change of coordinates*. In general, when you try to find one coordinate by performing a change of coordinates, you need to take into consideration *all* of the coordinates of the original system. "Time" in the X frame of reference frame is not merely a scaled version of "time" in the A frame of reference. X "time" and A "time" are *different axes in spacetime*. X "time" is a mixture of A "time" and A "space", and A "time" is a mixture of X "time" and X "space". This is why it's not contradictory to both say that X "time" flows more slowly in A's frame of reference and that A's "time" flows more slowly in X's frame of reference.